# Client Potential XSS without being properly sanitized or validated

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, checkmarx

I am getting the below message on checkmarx scan on my code.
Gets user input for the text
element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is
eventually displayed to the user in method
Below is my code. Could some help me how to sanitize the below scenario.

Script as follows:

```
function setSummary(select,summary,lim, summaryHidden, limHidden) {
    if(select[select.selectedIndex].value == '-1') {
        summary.innerHTML = '';
        lim.innerHTML = '';
        summaryHidden.value = '';
        limHidden.value = '';
    } else {
        summary.innerHTML = 'Test1 - '+select[select.selectedIndex].text;
        summaryHidden.value = 'Test2 - '+select[select.selectedIndex].text;
        lim.innerHTML = 'Virtual - '+select[select.selectedIndex].text;
        limHidden.value = 'Virtual - '+select[select.selectedIndex].text;
    }
}
```

I am getting checkmarx vulnerability at below line for without being properly sanitized or validated

```
summary.innerHTML = 'Test1 - '+select[select.selectedIndex].text;
```

Could some please help me, How to properly sanitize the above line.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not this is exploitable, really depends on the context of how this function is being called, where the object `select` is coming from (and how it is populated - is this ever externally controllable?)

Regardless, the simplest solution here would be to set the value to the `innerText` property, instead of `innerHTML`, like so:

```
summary.innerText = 'Test1 - ' + select[select.selectedIndex].text;
```